# how to pop back when using button as well as swipe gesture on a viewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

i have 2 scenarios here. 1. With button click from VC1 i want to move to VC6 and then swipe back. This is done by above mentioned code. 2. i also have swipe gesture in VC1 to move to VC2, Vc3, VC4, VC5 and VC6.Now i want to swipe back from VC6 to VC5,Vc4,VC3,VC2 and then to VC1. I can implement these 2 scenarios separately. But how can i implement these scenarios together.

I have six viewControllers. On `viewController1` I have a button which takes me to the `viewController6`. And i then pop back to `viewController5`, `viewController4`, `viewController3`, `viewController2` and `viewController1` respectively from `viewController6` using code

```
    - (IBAction)SwipeGoto5:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    IndexPage *P1VC=[[IndexPage alloc] initWithNibName:@"IndexPage" bundle:nil];
    Page2 *P2VC=[[Page2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page2" bundle:nil];
    Page3 *P3VC=[[Page3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page3" bundle:nil];
    Page4 *P4VC=[[Page4 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page4" bundle:nil];
    Page5 *P5VC=[[Page5 alloc] initWithNibName:@"Page5" bundle:nil];

    NSLog(@"swipe to 5");
    NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    [allViewControllers insertObject:P1VC atIndex:1];
    [allViewControllers insertObject:P2VC atIndex:2];
    [allViewControllers insertObject:P3VC atIndex:3];
    [allViewControllers insertObject:P4VC atIndex:4];
    [allViewControllers insertObject:P5VC atIndex:5];

    self.navigationController.viewControllers=allViewControllers;
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

I also have `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on `viewController1` which takes me to `viewController2`, `viewController3`, `viewController4` and also to `viewController6`. How will i pop back from `viewController6` when i use `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` on `viewController1` and i also have above mentioned code.

Comment: when do you want to pop?

Comment: how will you be on vc 6 when you are swiping in vc1?

Comment: if you want to remove all view controller in the stack use pop to root view controller

Comment: i have 2 scenarios here. 1. With button click from VC1 i want to move to VC6 and then swipe back. This is done by above mentioned code. 2. i also have swipe gesture in VC1 to move to VC2, Vc3, VC4, VC5 and VC6.Now i want to swipe back from VC6 to VC5,Vc4,VC3,VC2 and then to VC1. I can implement these 2 scenarios separately. But how can i implement these scenarios together.

Comment: Have a state manager. i flag or something. If vc6 is pushed from vc1 flag gets set. else not. Then while popping check for the state and then pop.

Answer (score 0):

Get the swipe gesture(Right to left) and write the code of popViewController in it.

Comment: hi piyush, i understand this. But how can i implement 1. With button click from VC1 i want to move to VC6 and then swipe back. This is done by above mentioned code. 2. i also have swipe gesture in VC1 to move to VC2, Vc3, VC4, VC5 and VC6.Now i want to swipe back from VC6 to VC5,Vc4,VC3,VC2 and then to VC1 together.